# Closed form of $\sum_{i=k}^\infty i h {i \choose {k-1}} h^{k-1} (1-h)^{i - (k-1)}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, power-series, infinite-sequences

Is there a closed form solution to the expression below? Or, if there is no closed form solution but the series converges, is there some upper bound on this expression?

$$\mathbb E_{i \sim Q}[i] = \sum_{i=k}^\infty i Q(i) = \sum_{i=k}^\infty i h {i \choose {k-1}} h^{k-1} (1-h)^{i - (k-1)}$$

The assumptions on constants $k$ and $h$ are that $k > 0$ and $0 < h < 1$.

I'm out of my depth here, so any tips would be appreciated!

---

P.S. This is my first question on MathOverflow. Let me know if you need more context, or if there's anything I can do to improve the question itself.

Comment: It's weird that $i$ appears as the index in the summation, and appears in the left-hand term as well (which sounds cryptic to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider an infinite sequence of independent coin-tosses with probability $h$ of "heads" in each one.  $h {i \choose k-1} h^{k-1} (1-h)^{i-(k-1)}$ is the 
probability that in the first $i$ coin-tosses there are exactly $k-1$ heads and the $i+1$'th toss is also heads, i.e. that the $k$'th heads occurs on the $i+1$'th toss.  Your sum (if you started at $k-1$ rather than $k$) would thus be the expected number of tosses before (and not including) the $k$'th "heads".  This is a standard elementary probability problem: look up "Negative binomial distribution".

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{split}
  \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} i h \binom{i}{k-1} h^{k-1} (1-h)^{i-k+1}
    &= h^k (1-h)^{2-k} \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} i \binom{i}{k-1} (1-h)^{i-1} \\
    &= h^k (1-h)^{2-k} f(1-h),
\end{split}
$$
where $f(t) = \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} i \binom{i}{k-1} t^{i-1}$. We have (as formal power series)
$$
  \int f \, dt = \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} \binom{i}{k-1} t^i = t^{k-1} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \binom{j+k-1}{k-1} t^j = \frac{t^{k-1}}{(1-t)^k} - t^{k-1}
$$
(the subtraction is because the sum starts at $i=k$ instead of $k-1$). So
$$
  f = \frac{d}{d t} \left( \frac{t^{k-1}}{(1-t)^k} - t^{k-1} \right),
$$
whatever that is, and your sum is $h^k (1-h)^{2-k} f(1-h)$.